# Is it good practice to re-define lapply() as mclapply()

Tags: r

For example, write

```
lapply <- function(X, FUN, ...) mclapply(X, FUN, ..., mc.cores = 24L)
```

instead of writing `mclapply` throughout the code. This way if someone else wants to run the code on a windows laptop he can simply comment the function definition.

Are there any issues with this approach?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to set the `mc.cores` option somewhere in the code, so that if a user is on windows, `mclapply` behaves like `lapply`?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with the code as you have it is that it won't run for either Windows or non-Windows, thus forcing the user to make edits regardless of the operating system.  As @Alex mentioned in his comment, you can detect the operating system, and set `mc.cores` to 1 in the case of `R` running under Windows:

```
if (Sys.info()[['sysname']] == 'Windows') {
    num.cores <- 1                             # use only one core on Windows
} else {
    num.cores <- 24L                           # use multiple cores if Mac or Linux
}

mclapply(X, FUN, ..., mc.cores = num.cores)    # make call using correct number of cores
```

Comment: In your original code you were making two function calls on the same line, which will always fail.  But even if that code ran, you would be doing the same thing twice.